# Memoir custom title page and twocolumns

Tags: memoir, titles, two-column

Using the package memoir, I am having some trouble creating my (Oh so simple) custom title page.

In the preamble, I have this:

```
\documentclass[medievalpage,twosides,twocolumn,pdftex,final]{memoir}
```

So, I get two columns for the text which is what I want.  The definition I have for the title is this:

```
\newcommand*{\titleDS}{\begingroup
\newlength{\drop}
\drop = 0.08\textheight
\centering{
    {\Huge{The Title}}\\
    {\Large{A funky subtitle}}\\
    \vspace*{\drop}
    {by The Author}\\
}
\thispagestyle{title}
\endgroup}
```

Finally, in the document body, I have:

```
\pagestyle{empty}
\titleDS
\clearpage
```

What happens is that the title is centred on the left column and not in the centre.

What have done wrong?  I suspect it's really simple and I am just being dense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to put `\titleDS` in a `titlingpage` environment:

```
\begin{titlingpage}
\titleDS
\end{titlingpage}
```

My version of **memoir** doesn't know about the option `medievalpage`, just about the command `\medievalpage`. The explicit option `pdftex` should never be used (with the exception of the **crop** package in some cases). The correct option is `twoside` and not `twosides`.