# Oneside cover within a twosided LaTeX document

Tags: margins, covers

I'm writing my thesis and I'd like to have a onesided cover while the rest of the document is twoside, so to obtain the text and figures well-centered within the cover. Here is my main .tex file:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,onecolumn,openany]{book}
\usepackage{thesis}
\graphicspath{{plots/}}
\begin{document}

%\setboolean{@oneside}{false}
\include{cover/cover}
%\setboolean{@oneside}{true} 

\include{chapter1\chapter}
...
```

Furthermore, the default margins are too big, and so I'd like to change them. A first solution to this last problem was to change the document into a *twocolumn* one in the very first line of the code, and then, after the cover page, changing it into *\onecolumn*.

**EDIT**: my own answer (see below) doesn't give the *exact* result I wanted. Now the number of the pages are correctly put on opposite corners depending whether it's an odd or even page, but the left and right margins are the same. Actually, I would like "external" margins to be a little wider, to put there some notes (using *\marginpar*).

Thanks!

Comment: FYI: the _thesis_ package is just a library I created to change a few things about layout

Comment: You don't necessarily need to use the built-in titling and cover. You can hack your own together fairly easily. Memoir has some options for this. I think the command is '\titlingpage'. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24410/memoir-custom-title-page-and-twocolumns for some pointers (and the memoir manual).

Comment: I gave up on workarounds, and just created a separate cover page in tex, and separate main file with the actual thesis etc. When in print, you just say that they put it together correctly when binding it ;)

Comment: Yes, @dingo_d : sometimes it's the quickest way to solve a problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying all the possible permutations of the commands I know, I obtained a good result with the code below:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside,twocolumn,openany]{book}

\usepackage{thesis}
\graphicspath{{plots/}}

\begin{document}

    \include{cover/cover}

    %change into onecolumn-twoside
    \onecolumn
    \setboolean{@twoside}{true}

    \mainpagestyle

    \include{chapter1/chapter}
    \include{chapter2/chapter}
    \include{chapter3/chapter}

    \backmatter
    \twocolumn

    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}
    \bibliographystyle{siam}
    \bibliography{mybib.bib}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I wouldn't use `\include` for the cover, but `\input`. Without seeing a hint of the code in it it's difficult to help.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108268/redefining-include, as to why.